# Angular material, when adding a ripple it will fill instead of disappearing

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, angular-material

I'm developing a framework on top of angular material for easy usage. I want to know if there is a fill version of the `md-ink-ripple` directive so that the ripple is an actual fill color when it is been set.

```
<myDiv md-ink-ripple>
   <div class="md-ripple-container">
      // so in an active state this will fill "myDiv" with color and stay fully sized
      <div class="md-ripple"></div>
   </div>
</myDiv>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the color of the ripple effect on any element by using -

```
<md-list-item md-ink-ripple="#03A9F4">
</md-list-item>
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!